# Move 0's to end of array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to move all 0's in an array to the end of the array.

Example: [1, 10, 0, 5, 7] should result in [1, 10, 5, 7, 0].

I am open to doing a reverse loop or a regular loop.

I **cannot** create a new array.

Here is what I have so far:

```
for (int i = arr.length; i <= 0; --i) {
    if (arr[i] != 0) {
        arr[i] = arr.length - 1;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any constraints?

Comment: Walk along, if you find a zero not followed by a zero then swap. Repeat until no more swaps...

Comment: @bmorris591 Bubble sort?...

Comment: Side note: If you are using loop you stated in code then change  to `i>=0` from `i<=0`. Otherwise your for loop will never run.

Comment: @Gary McSperry you edited the question.  What do you mean you can't create a new loop?

Comment: @DaidCowden I meant to say that I cannot create a new array, my bad

Comment: @GaryMcSperry if you figured it out you should accept an answer.  I'm mentioning this because I see you're new (=

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### SIZE(n) where n = arr.size, retain ordering:

Create an array that is the same size as the initial array you need to remove 0s from.  Iterate over the original array and add each element to the new array provided it is not 0.  When you encounter a 0, count it.  Now, when you've reached the end of the first array, simply add the counted number of 0s to the end of the array.  And, even simpler, since Java initializes arrays to 0, you can forget about adding the zeroes at the end.

---

**Edit**

Since you have added the additional constraint of not being able to create a new array, we need to take a slightly different approach than the one I've suggested above.

#### SIZE(1)

I assume the array needs to remain in the same order as it was before the 0s were moved to the end. If this is not the case there is another trivial solution as detailed in Brads answer: initialize a "last zero" index to the last element of the array and then iterate backwards swapping any zeros with the index of the last zero which is decremented each time you perform a swap or see a zero.

#### SIZE(1), retain ordering:

To move the 0s to the end without duplicating the array and keeping the elements in the proper order, you can do exactly as I've suggested without duplicating the array but keeping two indices over the same array.

Start with two indices over the array.  Instead of copying the element to the new array if it is not zero, leave it where it is and increment both indices.  When you reach a zero, increment only one index.  Now, if the two indices are not the same, and you are not looking at a 0, swap current element the location of the index that has fallen behind (due to encountered 0s).  In both cases, increment the other index provided the current element is not 0.

It will look something like this:

```
int max = arr.length;
for (int i = 0, int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
  if (arr[j] != 0) {
    if (i < j) {
      swap(arr, i, j);
    }
    i++
  }
}
```

Running this on:

```
{ 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0 }
```

yeilds:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

I made a [fully working version](http://codepad.org/rnADiIZg) for anyone who's curious.

Comment: A new array of int's is defaulted to 0's so you wouldnt even need to keep a count or initialize.

Comment: In Java yes.  I didn't see the Java tag at first.  I assumed this was C.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Two choices come to mind

1. Create a new array of the same size, then Iterate over your current array and only populate the new array with values. Then fill the remaining entries in the new array with "zeros"
2. Without creating a new array you can iterate over your current array backwards and when you  encounter a "zero" swap it with the last element of your array. You'll need to keep a count of the number of "zero" elements swapped so that when you swap for a second time, you swap with the `last-1`  element, and so forth.

---

**[Edit]** 7 years after originally posting to address the "ordering" issue and "last element is zero" issues left in the comments

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] elements = new int[] {1,0,2,0,3,0};

        int lastIndex = elements.length-1;

        // loop backwards looking for zeroes
        for(int i = lastIndex; i >=0; i--) {
            if(elements[i] == 0) {
                // found a zero, so loop forwards from here
                for(int j = i; j < lastIndex; j++) {
                    if(elements[j+1] == 0 || j == lastIndex) {
                        // either at the end of the array, or we've run into another zero near the end
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        // bubble up the zero we found one element at a time to push it to the end
                        int temp = elements[j+1];
                        elements[j+1] = elements[j];
                        elements[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elements));
    }
}
```

Gives you...

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate on option 2 a little bit more? Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: this solution does not retain the order of the elements from the input.

Comment: This solution would fail if last element in the array is 0

Comment: "ordering" and "what if the last element is a zero" issues fixed

Answer (score 2):

Basic solution is to establish an inductive hypothesis that the subarray can be kept solved. Then extend the subarray by one element and maintain the hypothesis. In that case there are two branches - if next element is zero, do nothing. If next element is non-zero, swap it with the first zero in the row.

Anyway, the solution (in C# though) after this idea is optimized looks like this:

```
void MoveZeros(int[] a)
{

    int i = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
        if (a[j] != 0)
            a[i++] = a[j];

    while (i < a.Length)
        a[i++] = 0;

}
```

There is a bit of thinking that leads to this solution, starting from the inductive solution which can be formally proven correct. If you're interested, the whole analysis is here: [Moving Zero Values to the End of the Array](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=exercises/moving-zeros-to-end-of-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
var size = 10;
var elemnts = [0, 0, 1, 4, 5, 0,-1];
var pos = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < elemnts.length; i++) {
    if (elemnts[i] != 0) {
        elemnts[pos] = elemnts[i];
        pos++;
        console.log(elemnts[i]);
    }
}
for (var i = pos; i < elemnts.length; i++) {
    elemnts[pos++] = 0;
    console.log(elemnts[pos]);
}
```

Comment: 1,4,5,-1,-5,8,0,0,0,0

Answer (score 0):

```
int arrNew[] = new int[arr.length];
int index = 0;
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]!=0){
       arrNew[index]=arr[i];
       index++;
    }
}
```

Since the array of int's is initialized to zero(according to the [language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#4.12.5)). this will have the effect you want, and will move everything else up sequentially.

Edit: Based on your edit that you cannot use a new array this answer doesnt cover your requirements.  You would instead need to check for a zero(starting at the end of the array and working to the start) and swap with the last element of the array and then decrease the index of your last-nonzero element that you would then swap with next.  Ex:

```
int lastZero = arr.length - 1;
if(arr[i] == 0){
  //perform swap and decrement lastZero by 1 I will leave this part up to you
}
```

Comment: @David Cowden, sorry, wrote that comment without thinking...  pressed the enter key instead of backspace.

Decided to leave it, looks like homework.

Comment: I think swapping to the end would change the order of the other elements; you need to shift all the elements up instead

Comment: Right if he needs to maintain order then he would need that logic in the if block instead.  He didnt state whether he did or not so I am leaving the logic of the swap up to the OP(which is why I just have a comment in the block)

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// From a given array send al zeros to the end (C# solution)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="numbersArray">The array of numbers</param>
/// <returns>Array with zeros at the end</returns>
public static int[] SendZerosToEnd(int[] numbersArray)
{
    // Edge case if the array is null or is not long enough then we do
    // something in this case we return the same array with no changes
    // You can always decide to return an exception as well
    if (numbersArray == null ||
        numbersArray.Length < 2)
    {
        return numbersArray;
    }

    // We keep track of our second pointer and the last element index
    int secondIndex = numbersArray.Length - 2,
        lastIndex = secondIndex;

    for (int i = secondIndex; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        secondIndex = i;

        if (numbersArray[i] == 0)
        {
            // While our pointer reaches the end or the next element
            // is a zero we swap elements
            while (secondIndex != lastIndex ||
                numbersArray[secondIndex + 1] != 0)
            {
                numbersArray[secondIndex] = numbersArray[secondIndex + 1];
                numbersArray[secondIndex + 1] = 0;

                ++secondIndex;
            }
            // This solution is like having two pointers
            // Also if we look at the solution you do not pass more than 
            // 2 times actual array will be resume as O(N) complexity 
        }
    }
    // We return the same array with no new one created
    return numbersArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if question adds following condition.

1. Time complexity must be O(n) - You can iterate only once.
2. Extra
   space complexity must be O(1) - You cannot create extra array.

Then following implementation will work fine.

Steps to be followed :

1. Iterate through array & maintain a count of non-zero elements.
2. Whenever we encounter a non-zero element put at count location in array & also increase the count.
3. Once array is iterated completely put the zeros at end of array till the count reach to original length of array.

> ```
> public static void main(String args[]) {
>   int[] array = { 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 9 };
>   // Maintaining count of non zero elements
>   int count = -1;
>   // Iterating through array and copying non zero elements in front of array.
>   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
>       if (array[i] != 0)
>           array[++count] = array[i];
>   }
>   // Replacing end elements with zero
>   while (count < array.length - 1)
>       array[++count] = 0;
>   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
>       System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity = O(n), Space Complexity = O(1)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShiftZeroesToBack {

    int[] array;
    void shiftZeroes(int[] array) {

        int previousK = 0; 
        int firstTime = 0;

        for(int k = 0; k < array.length - 1; k++) {

            if(array[k] == 0 && array[k + 1] != 0 && firstTime != 0) {
                int temp = array[previousK];
                array[previousK] = array[k + 1];
                array[k + 1] = temp;
                previousK = previousK + 1;
                continue;
            }

            if(array[k] == 0 && array[k + 1] != 0) {
               int temp = array[k];
               array[k] = array[k + 1];
               array[k + 1] = temp;
               continue;
            }

            if(array[k] == 0 && array[k + 1] == 0) {
                if(firstTime == 0) {
                    previousK = k; 
                    firstTime = 1;
                }
            }

       }
   }

   int[] input(Scanner scanner, int size) {
       array = new int[size];
       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
       }
       return array;
   }

   void print() {
       System.out.println();
       for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
       }
       System.out.println();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       ShiftZeroesToBack sztb = new ShiftZeroesToBack();
       System.out.print("Enter Size of Array\t");
       int size = scanner.nextInt();
       int[] input = sztb.input(scanner, size);
       sztb.shiftZeroes(input);
       sztb.print();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say we have an array

```
[5,4,0,0,6,7,0,8,9]
```

Let's assume we have array elements between 0-100, now our goal is to move all 0's at the end of the array. 
now hold 0 from the array and check it with non zero element if any non zero element found swap with that element and so on, at the end of the loop we will find the solution.

**here is the code**

```
for (int i = 0; i < outputArr.length; i++) 
  {

      for (int j = i+1; j < outputArr.length; j++) 
  {
        if(outputArr[i]==0 && outputArr[j]!=0){

            int temp = outputArr[i];
            outputArr[i] = outputArr[j];
            outputArr[j] = temp;

        }

     }
        print outputArr[i]....
}
```

**output:**

```
[5,4,6,7,8,9,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i have implemented this. 
Time complexity: O(n) and Space Complexity: O(1)
Below is the code snippet:

```
int arr[] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 0};
int i=0, k = 0;
int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
  if(arr[i]==0)
    continue;
  arr[k++]=arr[i];
}
for(i=k;i<n;i++)
{
  arr[i]=0;
}

output: {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Explanation: using another variable k to hold index location, non-zero elements are shifted to the front while maintaining the order. After traversing the array, non-zero elements are shifted to the front of array and another loop starting from k is used to override the remaining positions with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code with 2 for loops:

```
int [] arr = {0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 5, 0, 9,};
int temp;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
{
  if (arr[i] == 0)
  {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) 
    {
      if (arr[j] != 0)
      {
        temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

output: [4, 2, 1, 1, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Answer (score 0):

This is One method of Moving the zeroes to the end of the array.

```
public class SeparateZeroes1  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = {0,1,0,3,0,0,345,12,0,13};

        movezeroes(a);      
    }

    static void movezeroes(int[] a) {
        int lastNonZeroIndex = 0;
     // If the current element is not 0, then we need to
        // append it just in front of last non 0 element we found.
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i]  != 0 ) {
            a[lastNonZeroIndex++] = a[i];
        }
    }//for


    // We just need to fill remaining array with 0's.
    for (int i = lastNonZeroIndex; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = 0;
    }   
   System.out.println( lastNonZeroIndex         );
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

    }
}
```

This is very simple in Python. We will do it with list comprehension

```
a =[0,1,0,3,0,0,345,12,0,13]
def fix(a):
    return ([x for x in a if x != 0] + [x for x in a if x ==0])

print(fix(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer a[] = {10,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,70,6,7,8,0,4,0};
            int flag = 0;int count =0;
                for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
                if(a[i]==0 ) {
                    flag=1;
                    count++;
                }else if(a[i]!=0) {
                    flag=0;
                }
                if(flag==0 && count>0 && a[i]!=0) {
                    a[i-count] = a[i];
                    a[i]=0;
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] nums = { 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4 };
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 3) {
            list1.add(nums[i]);
        } else if (nums[i] != 3) {
            list2.add(nums[i]);
        }
    }
    List<Integer> finalList = new ArrayList<>(list2);
    finalList.addAll(list1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] nums = {3,1,2,5,4,6,3,2,1,6,7,9,3,8,0,4,2,4,6,4};
    int i = 0;
    for(int j = 0, s = nums.length; j < s;) {
        if(nums[j] == 3)
            j++;
        else {
            int temp = nums[i];
            nums[i] = nums[j];``
            nums[j] = temp;
            i ++;
            j ++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Integer` array it can be as simple as

```
Integer[] numbers = { 1, 10, 0, 5, 7 };
Arrays.sort(numbers, Comparator.comparing(n -> n == 0));
```

For `int` array :

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 10, 0, 5, 7 };
 numbers = IntStream.of(numbers).boxed()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(n -> n == 0))
                    .mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
```

Output of both:

> [1, 10, 5, 7, 0]

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, you have an array like

```
int a[] = {0,3,0,4,5,6,0};
```

Then you can sort it like,

```
   for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++){
    if(a[i]==0 && a[j]!=0){
    a[i]==a[j];
    a[j]=0;
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void test1(){

    int [] arr = {0,1,0,4,0,3,2};   
    System.out.println("Lenght of array is " + arr.length);

    for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++){

        for(int j=0; j < arr.length - i - 1; j++){
            if(arr[j] == 0){
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[arr.length - i - 1]; 
                arr[arr.length - i - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
        System.out.println(arr[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of what you did here.

Answer (score 0):

#### Have a look at this function code:

```
vector<int> Solution::solve(vector<int> &arr) {
    int count = 0;  
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) 
        if (arr[i] != 0) 
            arr[count++] = arr[i]; 
    while (count < arr.size()) 
        arr[count++] = 0; 
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;

  class Solution {

  public static int[] moveZerosToEnd(int[] arr) {

  int j = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] != 0) {
      swap(arr, i, j);
      j++;
    }
   }
    return arr;
  }
 private static void swap(int arr[], int i, int j){
      int temp = arr[j];
      arr[j] = arr[i];
      arr[i] = temp;
   }

public static void main(String[] args) {
   int arr[] =new int[] {1, 10, 0, 2, 8, 3, 0, 0, 6, 4, 0, 5, 7, 0 };
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(moveZerosToEnd(arr)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Reimplemented this in Python:

**Pythonic way:**

```py
lst = [ 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0 ]

for i, val in enumerate(lst):
  if lst[i] == 0:
    lst.pop(i)
    lst.append(0)

print("{}".format(lst))
```

**@dcow's implementation in python:**

```py
lst = [ 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0 ]

i = 0                      # init the index value
for j in range(len(lst)):  # using the length of list as the range
  if lst[j] != 0:
    if i < j: 
      lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]  # swap the 2 elems.
  i += 1

 print("{}".format(lst))
```

Comment: Pythonic way out is `[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. It will not work

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [ 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0 ]

count = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != 0:
        a[count], a[i] = a[i], a[count]
        count += 1 

print(a)
#op [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. This will greatly improve the quality of your answer, and makes it more likely to attract upvotes.